# Matlab container.Map

Tags: matlab, oop

Currently I am programming some OOP oriented stuffs in MATLAB, and I am often using container `Map` class, which I want expand to an additional functionality. One short example:

```
map = containers.Map;

% Add pair to map
map('One') = 1;
map('Two') = 2;

% Call the hash map
val = map('One');
```

so as you can see on example, to call map object there is not called "any method", how I could implement something similar, that based on number of input and output argument can I automatically use desired method?

Comment: A method is called. Look at [operator overloading](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html), specifically at `subsindex` and `subsasgn`.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/250895) on Matlab Central.